# Display Image from Mongodb (MERN)

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, image, multer

I've been trying to display an image using react from mongodb. I used multer to upload images and worked like a charm but my problem is, it seems that I cant output my image from the database. Heres my code.

```
        <div className="img-preview">
          {fields.dishImage ? (
            <img
              src={`localhost:5000/${menu.dishImage}`}
              alt={menu.dishImage}
            />
          ) : (
            <p className="image-text">
              Image Preview <br /> Suggested Size 300x300
            </p>
          )}
        </div>
```

The menu.dishImage contains something like this `uploads/2020-07-15T09-13-56.569Zcovid palette.jpg`

And I am getting an Error like this

```
GET localhost:5000/uploads/2020-07-15T09-13-56.569Zcovid palette.jpg net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

When I am opening that path from another tab I am seeing that the image is being shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add `http://` in your url.

For example,

```
src={`http://localhost:5000/${menu.dishImage}`}
```

Ideally, You should use `base_url` from config so that you can use dynamic URLS.
Also, Use relative URLs instead of Static URLs

Comment: Thank you soooo much! works perfectly like a charm!

Comment: You welcome :) 
Just a friendly advice. Please try to follow best practises in your code! It will save you from trouble like this and save your time also!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can try this alternative approach,

PS: You have to alter your code a bit for this method,

if you are working with big files greater than 16mb please go with gridfs and multer, else you can try this

( changing the images to a different format and save them to mongoDB)

If your files are actually less than 16 mb, please try using this Converter that changes the image of format jpeg / png to a format of saving to mongodb, and you can see this as an easy alternative for gridfs ,

The main goal is to convert the image to another format and then store them in  mongoDB

i have put up a complete guide in this github repo, please to check them,

[please check this github repo for more details..](https://github.com/saran-surya/Mongo-Image-Converter)